# Can't access twitter profile URL - using STTwitter Wrapper

Tags: ios, twitter, swift, sttwitter

I'm using the STTwitter wrapper to connect with Twitter and I'm running AppOnly and I'm able to retrieve the tweet text with no problems. I'm using the `getStatusesUserTimelineForUserID` method for that.

The problem is that I can't access "twitter_profile_url" or "profile_banner_url" but I can access text and tweet time and tweet ID perfectly fine.

I did however manage to get the twitter_profile_url by using the `getUsersShowForUserID` method.

My question is that am I doing something wrong when trying to access twitter_profile_url with `getStatusesUserTimelineForUserID`? I looked over Twitter's documents and I think the reason why `getUsersShowForUserID` works is because of the includeEntities property. I'm not 100% sure on that so I was wondering if someone could clarify that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint [statuses/user_timeline.json](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) returns a list of tweets.

Each of these tweets has a `user` dictionary, and this dictionary should have keys such as `profile_image_url`, `profile_image_url_https`, `profile_banner_url`, `profile_background_image_url` or `profile_background_image_url_https`.

So yes, it should be working, and if not then please open an [issue on STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues) project and post the exact code you're using.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't going through the user dictionary when calling profile_image_url.